# Setting QgsLayoutItemLabel position by map coordinates in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, labeling, coordinates

I am making a layout export function and I would like to create a `QgsLayoutItemLabel` at a given latitude and longitude. But in `QgsLayout` the position is relative xy (150,100).

Is there a way to convert map coordinates to layout positions?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I find it.

```
def map_coords_to_position(self, mapx, mapy) -> QPointF:
    ppwu = self.map.pagePositionWithUnits();
    mtic = self.map.mapToItemCoords(QPointF(mapx, mapy))
    return QPointF(mtic.x() + ppwu.x(), mtic.y() + ppwu.y())
```

self.map is a QgsLayoutItemMap.

For example, you could add a polygon to a map in layout like this.

```
geom = QgsGeometry.fromWkt(wkt)
wkb_type = geom.wkbType()
if wkb_type == QgsWkbTypes.Polygon:
    p = QPolygonF()
    for v in geom.vertices():
        new_pt = self.map_coords_to_position(v.x(), v.y())
        p.append(QPointF(new_pt.x(), new_pt.y()))
    polygon = QgsLayoutItemPolygon(p, self.layout)            
    self.layout.addItem(polygon)
```

It is tested in QGIS 3.4.2.